# Using Visual Studio Code with SumatraPDF to open LaTeX source files

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-code, latex, pdflatex, sumatra-pdf

When you double click on a PDF file opened with SumatraPDF in Windows OS, it'll invoke a command (see the blue rectangle in the following image).

[image]

If the PDF file and its LaTeX source file are in the same folder, then double clicking on the PDF file will open the source file with notepad. However, I do not know what to enter instead of `notepad %f` so that the source file is opened in Visual Studio Code. Any ideas?

Comment: Associate the source file with vscode.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I meant double-clicking on the **PDF file** so vscode opens the source file (this is currently the case for notepad not vscode). I didn't mean double-clicking on the source file.

Comment: And how vscode will know the corresponding source file of that specific PDF?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I just know that notepad can recognise the corresponding source file. I think vscode is advanced enough to be able to do that, but I don't know how.

Comment: Doesn't `code %f` work?

Comment: @ihmels I already tried this and some variants of it but none of them works. It says "Can't start inverse search command".

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the LaTeX workshop package and configure it so the inverse search works correctly. Instructions are outlined in the [LaTeX Workshop wiki](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/View#sumatrapdf).

---

#### What you need to do

Firstly, you need to ensure you have the extension [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop)  installed in VSCode.

1. Change the following lines in `Settings > Advanced Options...`, replacing `<YOUR_USERNAME>` and `<OS_DRIVE>` to point to the correct VSCode executable (and make sure to overwrite the values, don't just add this to the end, or settings won't be used):

```
InverseSearchCmdLine = "<OS_DRIVE>:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" -r -g "%f:%l"
EnableTeXEnhancements = true
```

2. Once you've done this, go into your VSCode settings JSON (`CTRL + SHIFT + P` > select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`) then add the following lines:

```
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external",
  "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.command": "<OS_DRIVE>:/Users/<YOUR_USERNAME>/AppData/Local/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe",
  "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.synctex.args": [
    "-forward-search",
    "%TEX%",
    "%LINE%",
    "-reuse-instance",
    "-inverse-search",
    "\"<OS_DRIVE>:\\Users\\<YOUR_USERNAME>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" -r -g \"%f:%l\"",
    "%PDF%"
  ],
```

and that's it...

You can also add this to your `settings.json` if you want to open the preview in sumatra aswell:

```
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.command": "<OS_DRIVE>:/Users/<YOUR_USERNAME>/AppData/Local/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe"
```

---

This setup works for me on SumatraPDF `v3.4.6 (64-bit)` and VSCode `1.78.2` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Forward/Reverse Search is a PDFTeX mechanism for "PDFsync"ing (very much like temporary Hyperlinks in the PDF)

```
ForwardSearch [
    HighlightOffset = 0
    HighlightWidth = 15
    HighlightColor = #6581ff
    HighlightPermanent = false
]
```

it only needs :-

- A PDF and a companion PDFSync or SyncTeX file which was compiled at the same time.
- A PDF reader that understands those relationships, and a flag as to which editor the reply is to be sent to.

So any known editor will do and its possible in Windows to write LaTeX in MS Notepad so Double Click a line can trigger the file in "Default MS Notepad" as shown.
[image]

### HOWEVER

MS Notepad would not know which line wants an external "goto" command that dialog needs VBS code to function, ***see footnote*** so the Notepad.exe refer back is simply a confidence test at file level, that SyncTeX is working, perfectly in the viewer, and any problems are then down to configuration.

There are **many** dozens of LaTeX editor so only a few will be auto-configured by SumatraPDF application detection, when `EnableTeXEnhancements = true`, and VSCode.exe with a LaTeX extender, has changed its methods several times!

Technically it unsupported by LaTeX-Workshop for calling SumatraPDF ! see https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/View#using-synctex-with-an-external-viewer

So, most LaTeX editors like NotePad++ (notepad++.exe "%f" -n%l) etc. can send their location at time of compilation and that is the reason for -inverse-search command ONLY NEEDED ONCE by the viewer to re-configure for THAT editor. Thus NO NEED **after first invocation** for ""-inverse-search", and following exe line" in the editor, it can if sent repeatedly all day long, simply cause issues. likewise `-reuse-instance` should be set as `ReuseInstance = true` in the settings and not sent repeatedly. see https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/1197

Inverse searcher can be sent ONCE by the TeX editor or very easily for multiple editors, by any external command such as a batch file OR manually, then it is **stored in the PDF viewers settings** until changed again.
For VSCode.exe you can use

```
-g or --goto    When used with file:line{:character}, opens a file at a specific line and optional character position. This argument is provided since some operating systems permit : in a file name.
```

also

```
-r or --reuse-window    Forces opening a file or folder in the last active window.
```

thus the normal inverse search command will usually be

`"c:\path...\.\.\...to\code.exe" -r -g "%f:%l"`  (that is Lower case L for line)

using short -switches and omitting the {:%c} as usually non functional
[image]

For others using electron it may be in json terms be needed as per the Wiki https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/View#sumatrapdf

`"C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node -r -g "%f:%l"`

However SumatraPDF does not run JS as such, so there it may be different.

### BE aWARE (YMMV)

SumatraPDF 3.4.6 (64 bit installed) can have issues reading some SyncTeX compression formats, thus use 32 bit installed or 64 bit portable OR remove the PDFTeX compress synctex.gz flag.

***Most/all ? such issues should have been fixed in pre-release 3.5.15388 onwards***

[footnote] to see how SyncTeX works without LaTeX active there is a notepad TeXtPaD demo script in zip at bottom of comment  https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/discussions/3489#discussioncomment-6018474
[image]